# Authors frequently mention the convergence of their reinforcement learning algorithms. Do they imply a local or a global convergence?

Tags: machine-learning, convergence, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I frequently come across authors in reinforcement learning papers mentioning that some or the other algorithm *converges*. Do they mean a local convergence or a global convergence? What do they specifically refer to, when they just mention *convergence*?

Take the example of this paper **'Convergence of a Q-learning Variant for Continuous States and Actions'** (https://www.jair.org/media/4271/live-4271-7865-jair.pdf).

Comment: In general, convergence need not be to a global optimum, a local optimum, or even a saddlepoint. It's easy to write an algorithm which always converges to 0.  However, in the linked paper, the convergence is described as being to an optimum policy, which I think (but am not 100% sure) means globally optimal policy.

Comment: I don't actually get it. The concept of optimality is thrown around quite a lot giving it an air of lesser importance, as if the type of optimum does not actually matter. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it is commendable that you're thinking about the matter.  There's lots of loose talk and loose thinking.  I was pointing out that mere convergence, does not even mean there is convergence to any optimum. Many people write algorithms which either don't converge, or id they do converge, may converge to something which is in no way a solution to the problem they are trying to solve. I've seen programs which converged to a local or even global maximum, and the program ncorrectly claimed that it converged to a local minimum.

Comment: how do they know it's global in real life situation?

Comment: @aksakal - There's the whole issue of an algorithm appearing to converge in practice when it has not, as well as the above points.  I recently read an RL paper in which the authors recommended 20 restarts with different random number seeds and starting locations - as an improvement over the current practice of 5 - 10 restarts - for inventory control problems.  So my answer to your question is, as one might expect, "they don't."

Answer (score 0):

With Reinforcement Learning, the algorithms usually converge to a global optimum. Satton and Barto's [book](https://webdocs.cs.ualberta.ca/~sutton/book/the-book.html) covers the basic proofs in the Dynamic Programming chapter.

Comment: What got me confused is a chapter in the book **Reinforcement learning-state of the art** by Otterlo/Wiering. Paraphrasing from the chapter on function approximations, "_A drawback of non-linear function approxima- tion in reinforcement learning is that less convergence guarantees can be given. In some cases, convergence to a local optimum can be assured (e.g., Maei et al, 2009), but in general the theory is less well developed than for linear approximation._". Now the paper I mentioned also dealt with kernel approximators, so does the statement of global convergence of RL still hold?